# is there a way to get the number of agents with or without tasks in a particular queue?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I'm working on queue stats dashboard. there is a taskrouter api endpoint which provides stats about the agents state.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/taskqueue-statistics#

```
"activity_statistics": [
{
  "friendly_name": "Idle",
  "workers": 0,
  "sid": "WAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
{
  "friendly_name": "Busy",
  "workers": 9,
  "sid": "WAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
{
  "friendly_name": "Offline",
  "workers": 6,
  "sid": "WAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
{
  "friendly_name": "Reserved",
  "workers": 0,
  "sid": "WAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

it provides number of workers in each state.
Now lets say the agent is in status busy, but its possible that agent might not have any tasks assigned.
is there a way to get the number of agents of a particular queue without any tasks assigned to them regardless of what status they are in?